# How can I find charge from output signal of the Photo Mulitipier Tube?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, charge

[image]

Here I have a scintillator detector with PMT, It give a signal when a particle passing through it.
I need to find the total charge from the signal.
How can I find charge from the signal?

Comment: What is a PMT? What is the particle you're talking about? What are you measuring? How does your measurement setup look like? We're not sitting in the same lab as you, and realizing that we can't read you mind would be probably very helpful in all your scientific or technological efforts.

Comment: @MarcusMüller hi, Photo Multiplier tube is connected with scintillator when a particle(any with sufficient energy) it create a photon this photon sensed by the PMT and PMT gives corresponding signal (in pic), here I want to find the total charge, from that I can find the energy,So I need a way to calculate to total charge

Comment: Don't sprinkle information in comments. Edit your question. Sentances start with capital letter. I is spelled with capital letter. Question mark follows each question.

Comment: @winny this is my first question that's why

Comment: @krishnamoorthijayakumar no, you simply didn't write a sufficiently detailed question. It has nothing to do with whether this is your first question here: It's not the first question you ever ask someone! How could you think someone not sitting in your lab even knows what you're referring to? Nearly all of the questions in my first comment are still open, so edit your question to include all the answers, or your question would probably be closed very soon because it's totally unclear.

Comment: *this is my first question* And how is that an excuse? A better excuse would be "I did not know I could Edit" / "I could not find the edit function". You just run into a problem, don't know how to solve it and then cry "help!" on this site. This site doesn't work like that, we expect you to do some research. If the charge was doubled, how would that affect the trace on the scope ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie if the charge doubled then the height of the signal and the rising time also increase

Comment: @krishnamoorthijayakumar like this ? https://ibb.co/nruu8J

Comment: @johnger thanks for that can you give some more detail

Comment: @krishnamoorthijayakumar https://www.hamamatsu.com/resources/pdf/etd/PMT_handbook_v3aE-Chapter7.pdf

Comment: How can we see your calibration sticker?  https://www.google.com/search?num=50&client=firefox-b&ei=y3oOW4eWOOy_jwTp06DICQ&q=scintillator+detector+with+PMT+calibration&oq=scintillator+detector+with+PMT+calibration&gs_l=psy-ab.3...359172.363008.0.363452.12.12.0.0.0.0.208.1429.2j9j1.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.10.1126...33i160k1j33i21k1.0.95M-tZ06jBY  and what experiment?

Comment: It's easier to edit the question yourself than berate the OP, then tell the OP the best practices. Give people a break on their first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is back calculate the Photo Multiplier Tube (PMT) Current at the anode pin of the PMT.

If you have only a transimpedance amplifier the equation to transfer between the two the equation is:

\$ V = I*R\$

where V is equal to the output voltage of the amplifier and R is equal to the resistor (and is the gain). If you have an addtional gain stage you will need to account for that. If the transimpedance amplifier is capacitively coupled you'll have to account for that also and is a different equation.

Once you have calculated your anode current (or have a time series graph)

\$ I = \frac{\Delta Q}{\Delta T} \$

or rearranging

\$ \int Idt = Q\$

so if you integrate the current of the anode over time, you can find out the total charge. If you wanted to do this with your scope plot, depending on the gain circuit you have, it may be as simple as dividing the voltage of the scope by the gain and then integrating across the pulse.

Comment: I have to do this work by designing electronics circuit